# Understanding the monotonous convergence theorem

Tags: measure-theory, monotone-functions

I'm stuck at the next point in the proof of this theorem

> **Monotone Convergence Theorem**: If $(f_n)$ is a monotone increasing sequence of nonnegative measurable functions which converges to $f$,
> then $$\int f d\mu=\lim\int f_n d\mu$$

How the integral preserves order in functions we have
$$\int f_n \leq \int f_{n+1} \leq \int f d\mu$$
Then the succession of integrals is monotone increasing and in a certain sense, it is bounded by $\int f d\mu$.
But, what happens if the integral of some $f_n$ is infinite? would have
$$+\infty\leq+\infty\leq\cdots+\infty\leq+\infty$$
Is this correct? I know it has to do with the integral taking values ​​in the extended reals, but I don't see the point in the inequality of infinities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is correct.

The point is that once the integral is infinite, it *stays* infinite. So if $\int f_n\,\mathrm{d}\mu=\infty$ for some $n$, then $\int \lim_n f_n\,\mathrm{d}\mu=\infty$.

In the extended reals, $+\infty$ is the maximum, so if something is greater or equal than $+\infty$, it must be equal to it.

Comment: Thanks for clearing the doubt.

Answer (score 3):

If $\int f_n=\infty$ for some $n$ then $\int f_m=\infty$ for all $m \geq n$ and $\int f =\infty$ so $\int f=\lim \int f_n$

Comment: Does it have to do with the fact that there are infinites greater than others? But it seems that those infinities are the same.

Comment: @DavidMorante: Not at all. In the extended reals, there are only two infinities: $-\infty$ and $+\infty$.